# C++ Boolean Function Operands

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, boolean

So I've started working with c++ for my university classes and it's been going really well so far. There's a dilemma I'm having with a current question and I've got the basic code structure all figured out, there's just one problem with my output.

What I'm looking for e.g;

```
if (bool variable = true){ 

  output

else
  alternate output
```

I'm aware that this isn't a free debugging service place, but it would really help me in future projects as well and there aren't any *bugs*, it executes just fine.

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
bool calculateBox(double, double, double, double *, double *);

int main()
{
    //defining variables
    double length, width, height, volume, surfaceArea;

    cout << "Hello and welcome to the program.\nPlease enter the dimensions for the box in [cm](l w h): ";
    cin >> length >> width >> height;
    calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea);

    if (bool calculateBool = true) {
        cout << "Volume: " << volume << "cm^3" << endl << "Surface Area: " << surfaceArea << "cm^2" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error, value(s) must be greater than zero!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//functions
bool calculateBox(double length, double width, double height, double * volume, double * surfaceArea) {
    if ((length > 0) && (width > 0) && (height > 0)) {
        *surfaceArea = length * width * 6;
        *volume = length * width * height;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

*Key, if the values **do not** meet the requirements, the output displays not the error message, but a strange string for surfaceArea and volume. It appears to skip over the 'else' statement.

My question - does my error lie within the return statements in the function? Or is it a logic problem with my 'if' statement in the main method?

Comment: Your `if` condition always evaluates to true. What did you mean for that to do?

Comment: `if (bool calculateBool = true)` creates a new variable, `calculateBool`, and initializes it to true. Not what you want. I suspect what you want is more like `if (calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea)){ `, but this is just a suspicion.

Comment: unrelated: in `bool calculateBox(double length, double width, double height, double * volume, double * surfaceArea)` consider using references instead of pointers: `bool calculateBox(double length, double width, double height, double & volume, double & surfaceArea)` References are generally easier to work with and harder to screw up than pointers.

Comment: @user4581301 My man, you are a genius. I had originally stated


if ((calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea)) = true){


But now I understand that the return value itself is actually true. This actually solved all my problems, thanks so much!

Comment: As for the second point, I agree that would be easier to work with but the current project outlines "use of pointers for c++ solutions". Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: `if ((calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea)) = true)` went wrong on you because `=` is used to assign, not test for equality. Use `==` to test. What you wrote tried to assign true to what the function returned. The compiler spits out an error message because that's not really meaningful. But read [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) to learn when it is useful.

Comment: Check with the instructor on what the goal of the lesson is, but that's not a good use for a pointer in C++. It is in C though.

Comment: Ah I see, variable assignment vs. equality checking is something I missed when proofreading my code. I'll take a look at that article for sure! I'll send him an email for clarification then - I just saw the article  [reference vs pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1). Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```
if (bool calculateBool = true)
```

the `bool calculateBol` part will cause a local variable named `calculateBool` be defined as a bool.  The `= true`  part means to assign what's on the left of `=`to the value true.  The whole `bool calculateBool = true` will therefore be true so that that the else clause will never be executed.

Note that the the occurence of a single `=` in a condition should always ring the bell that bad signs could happen.  Because comparing for equality is `==`.

This being said,  you could write:

```
 if (calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea)) {
```

or if you need the value later on:

```
bool calculateBool = calculateBox(length, width, height, &volume, &surfaceArea);
if (calculateBool) {  // or calculateBool==true if you prefer
```

Comment: This is a much more in-depth solution to my problem. And it's really clear as to what I did wrong, I'll know to look out for that next time. Creating the local variable vs calling the function seems to have been my main problem. Really appreciate it, Christophe!